# How can I display an image within the WPF Aero Glass Titlebar?

Tags: .net, wpf, aero

I have standard WPF Window that I have extended the Aero Glass on the top of the window around 50 pixels.  I would like to keep the standard Min. Max. and Close buttons, Title Text and Window Icon.

I would like to display a few small images (i.e. icons) in the title bar, around the middle of the title bar.  How could I do this?  WPF will not display the images if I place them near the title bar, I assume as the title bar is non-client area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [WPF Chrome project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/chrome) on code.msdn.com.
It draws an image on the title bar.